# Regular expression matching for removing certain uses of the period character

Tags: regex, sed, fortran

I have some Fortran 77 source files that I'm trying to convert from a non-standard `STRUCTURE` and `RECORD` syntax to the standardized Fortran 90 `TYPE` syntax. One tricky aspect of this is the different way that structure members are addressed.

Non-standard:

```
s.member = 1
```

Standard:

```
s%member = 1
```

So, I need to trap all uses of periods in these sort of scenarios and replace them with `%` characters. Not too bad, except when you think about all of the ways that periods can be used (decimal points in numbers, filenames in `include` statements, punctuation in comments, Fortran 77 relational operators, maybe others). I've done some preprocessing to fix the relational operators to use the Fortran 90 symbols, and I don't really care about mangling the grammar of comments, but I haven't come up with a good approach to translate the `.` to `%` for the cases above. It seems like I should be able to do this with sed, but I'm not sure how to match the instances I need to fix. Here are the rules that I've thought of:

On a line-by-line basis:

- If the line begins with `<whitespace>include`, then we shouldn't do anything to that line; pass it through to the output, so we don't mess up the filename inside the include statement.
- The following strings are operators that don't have symbolic equivalents, so they must be left alone: `.not. .and. .or. .eqv. .neqv.`
- Otherwise, if we find a period that is surrounded by 2 non-numeric characters (so it's not a decimal point), then it should be the operator that I'm looking to replace. Change that period to a `%`.

I'm not a native Fortran speaker myself, so here are some examples:

```
include 'file.inc'        ! We don't want to do anything here. The line can
                          ! begin with some amount of whitespace

if x == 1 .or. y > 2.0    ! In this case, we don't want to touch the periods that
                          ! are part of the logical operator ".or.". We also don't
                          ! want to touch the period that is the decimal point 
                          ! in "2.0".
if a.member < 4.0 .and. b.othermember == 1.0 ! We don't want to touch the periods
                                             ! inside the numbers, but we need to
                                             ! change the "a." and "b." to "a%"
                                             ! and "b%".
```

Any good way of tackling this problem?

**Edit:** I actually found some additional operators that contain a dot in them that don't have symbolic equivalents. I've updated the rule list above.

Comment: Input with all or some of the cases would be nice for non fortran users :)

Comment: FORTRAN variable names can contain numbers, but since the first character has to be a letter, you might want to use something like this: \w[a-zA-Z0-9()]{0,5}\.\w

Comment: How many total "structures" do you have in total, and how many fields do they have collectively?  It may be easiest just to search for \.field1 and change to %field1, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that floating point numbers in Fortran can also look like 1.e0 1.d0 ...

Comment: @Jonathan: Many structures, many fields, lots of source files. It's definitely possible to do this by hand, but as an engineer, I'm, by definition, lazy.

Comment: @alexurba: Good point. I don't think that type of notation is used in these files, and if it is in a few places, I should be able to fix those by hand afterwards.

Comment: Don't forget `.true.` and `.false.`, and don't forget that Fortran has no reserved words, so technically variables or structure members could be named `include`, `and`, `true`, and so on, making it enormously difficult to distinguish between keywords and identifiers; obviously, that's why the standard commitee went with `%` as member separator instead of `.`. Now, it would take quite a perverse programmer to write code with such identifiers, but Fortran's history is unfortunately not completely devoid of such persons ;-).

Comment: Oh, and of course in fixed form whitespace is non-significant, so e.g. include could be spelled `i n c l ude`.

Comment: Just how big is the codebase; n# of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a regexp, and it's not that easy.

If I had to do what you have to, I would probably do it by hand, unless the codebase is huge. If the former applies, first replace all [a-zA-Z0-9].[a-zA-Z] to something very weird that is guaranteed never to compile, something like "@WHATEVER@", then proceed to search all these entries and replace them by hand after manual control.

If the amount of code is huge, then you need to write a parser. I would suggest you to use python to tokenize basic fortran constructs, but remember that fortran is not an easy language to parse. Work "per routine", and try to find all variable names used, using them as a filter. If you encounter something like `a.whatever`, and you know that `a` is in the list of local or global vars, apply the change.

Comment: I agree that it isn't easy, but I do have a lot of files. I'm hoping to find a solution short of building a full-blown language parser. Your tip of replacing with sentinel values might help. I can get all of the operators (e.g. ".and.") out of the way by first replacing them with strings that I consider very improbable, then putting it back later. What would be left is detecting a period surrounded by characters that appear to be valid for variable names, which shouldn't be too bad. This is for my convenience, not for any production-level system, so a hack is suitable.

Comment: Way late to the party but: software like some IDE's can search a pattern, list all results and let you remove the ones you don't want to replace. The same idea but much easier. (Jetbrains IDEs for example, doesn't really matter that they're not for Fortran)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the codebase is really ***HUUGE*** (and do think very hard whether this is indeed the case), I'd just take an editor like **Vim** (*vertical select & block select are your friends*) a***nd set aside an afternoon to do this by hand***. In one afternoon, my guess is you'll be done with ***most of it, if not all***. ***Afternoon is a lot of time. Just imagine how many cases you could've covered in these 2 hours alone.***

Just by ***trying to write a parser for something like this, will take you much longer than that.***

Of course, the question begs itself ... if the code if F77 which all compilers still support, and the code works ... why are you so keen on changing it?

Comment: On the last paragraph: the whole point is that the code is not standard F77, but makes use of vendor specific extensions. However, it might be worth it to check if any current compilers allow this extension.

Comment: @eriktous - Aware of that. But the point was, a lot of, what were vendor extensions in F77 is now standard, and those that are not, are supported and by other compilers today.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that versed in regexps, so I guess I'd try tackling one this from other side. If you `grep` for the `STRUCTURE` keyword, you get the list of all the `STRUCTURES` used in the code. Once you have it, for each `STRUCTURE S` then you can just replace all instances of `S.` by `S%`.

This way you don't have to worry about things like `.true.`, `.and.`, `.neq.` and their relatives. The main worry then would be to be able to parse the `STRUCTURE` declarations.

Comment: The problem is with the members of the STRUCTURE.  So first one would have to look for all STRUCTURE definitions and then for all declarations of variables of that type.

Comment: yes, exactly. from the output of `grep STRUCTURE *.f` (assuming it's some *nix) it's not too hard to get the names of the variables, then for each of the variables it's basically `grep variable-name.`

Answer (score 0):

Although the regex below :

```
(?<!')\b([^.\s]+)(?<!\.(?:not|and|or|eqv|neqv))(?<=\D)\.(?=\D)(?!(?:not|and|or|eqv|neqv)\.)([^.\s]+)\b(?!')
```

Replace `$1%$2`

Works perfectly for your examples, I would not recommend using it with your current task. It will definitely not cover all your cases. Now if you care for a 80% coverage or something you could use it but you should probably back up your sources. With the limited set of input cases I had , I am sure that there will be cases that the regex would replace something that it shouldn't.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This sed oneliner might be a start

```
sed -r '/^\s*include/b;/^\s*! /b;G;:a;s/^(\.(not|and|or|eqv|neqv)\.)(.*\n.*)/\3\1/;ta;s/^\.([^0-9]{2,})(.*\n.*)/\2%\1/;ta;s/^(.)(.*\n.*)/\2\1/;ta;s/\n//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, I am guessing it would be enough to protect quoted strings, then replace periods with alphabetics on both sides.

```
perl -pe '1 while s%(\x27[^\x27]+)\.([^\x27]+\x27)%$1@@::@@$2%;
    s/([a-z])\.([a-z])/$1%$2/g;
    s/@@::@@/./g' file.f
```

I offer this Perl solution not because sed is not a good enough tool for this, but because it avoids the issue of minor but pesky differences between sed dialects. The ability to use a hex code for the single quotes is a nice bonus.